# django - urlconf request mapping and views not reached

Tags: python, django, django-forms, get, django-views

i have a form in a template, but it can't reach the correspondant view. the method is GET. i've tried also to pass it an argument just to populate the query string, but the request doesnt reach the mapped view. here'sthe views.py, urls.py and the template:

**template.html**

```
<div id="search-new-btn">
    <form action="/anagrafica/new/" method="get">
        <input type="submit" title="Crea nuovo soggetto anagrafica" value="Nuovo" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def anagrafica_new(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':      
        form = AnagraficaForm()
        sub = 'Nuovo soggetto anagrafica'
        dict = {'sub':sub,'form':form}
        return render_to_response('anagrafica_form.html', dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^anagrafica/new/',('gpf1.views.anagrafica_new')),
...
```

(http://openpaste.org/05b157c1)

Anyway, i've also tried to remove the () from the callback url.py mapping, but it didnt change nothing.
the request seems to be mapped cause my debug server print this:

```
"GET /anagrafica/new/? HTTP/1.1" 200 17310
```

but nothing more. the browser remain on the same page; i also put a print statement just inside the view but it never has been reached. any idea?

thanks,
Luke

Comment: perhaps you should change anagrafica/new/ by anagrafica_new on urls.py

Comment: William, could you explain me?

Comment: url(r'^anagrafica/new/', 'gpf1.views.anagrafica_new'). I'm not sure what your problem is, the templates gets rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Willian` suggested don't put the view in a tuple. Another thing you are missing is the $ at the end of regular expression i.e.:

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^anagrafica/$','gpf1.views.anagrafica'),
...
url(r'^anagrafica/new/$','gpf1.views.anagrafica_new'),
...
```

Make sure that the folder containing gpf1 package is within Pythonpath variable (reachable by python).

Edit:
Subsequently I noticed you have a root url map for

```
url(r'^anagrafica/','gpf1.views.anagrafica')
```

Since you are missing $ at the end Django will try to map `anagrafica/anything here` to `gpf1.views.anagrafica` which is probably not what you want. Consider rereading regular expressions and Django's url mapping documentation as it will make things a bit clearer.

Comment: it doesn't work. anyway this is my urlconf: http://openpaste.org/3F72093f. as you can see there are other urls mapping similar to that (e.g. /preventivo/new/), with a get requets and gat parameters not mapped with a python regex. but they works...

Comment: Reason being is that you have ``` url(r'^anagrafica/', ('gpf1.views.anagrafica')),``` which will map anything that starts with ```anagrafica/``` including ```anagrafica/new/``` to gpf1.views.anagrafica view. Again $ to the end of it too. See updated answer.